# Makefile error on C program "expected ‘)’ before ‘{’ token"

Tags: c

I get an error when I try to make the Makefile on the following C program.

```
int main()
{
    char  filename_src[101], filename_dest[101];

    printf("\nSource file: ");
    gets_s(filename_src, 100);

    printf("\nDestination filename: ");
    gets_s(filename_dest, 100);

    if(copy_file(filename_src, filename_dest) == 0)
        printf("Copy Successful\n");
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during copy!");

    copyfile( filename_src, filename_dest );
}

int copyfile( const char *test1, const char *test2 )
{
    int infile, outfile;
    ssize_t nread;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];

    if( ( infile = open(test1, O_RDONLY) ) == -1 )
      return (-1);

    if( ( outfile = open(test2,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,PERM ) == -1)
    {
        close(infile);
        return (-2);
    }
    /* now read from test1 BUFSIZE chars at a time*/
    while( (nread = read(infile, buffer, BUFSIZE) ) > 0)
    {
        /*write buffer to output file*/
        if( write(outfile, buffer, nread) < nread )
        {
            close(infile);
            close(outfile);
            return (-3);        /*write error*/
        }
    }

    close(infile);
    close(outfile);

    if( nread == -1 )
      return (-4);              /*error on last read*/

    else
      return (0);               /*all is well */
}
```

This is my C program. I get the error "expected ‘)’ before ‘{’ token" when I try to make the Makefile on terminal. Can anyone tell me where the problem in my code is?

Thank you

Comment: The error message will include a line number. If you don't know how to find the line number in the error message, please include the *complete* error message in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if  ( ( outfile = open(test2,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,PERM ) == -1)
    ^ 2               1                                    1      2
```

As you can see this parenthesis is unmatched.